# Passing arrays to functions in Perl

Tags: perl, function, parameter-passing

I think I have misunderstood some aspects of argument passing to functions in Perl. What's the difference between `func(\@array)` and `func(@array)`?

AFAIK, in both functions, arguments are passed by reference and in both functions we can change the elements of `@array` in the main program. So what's the difference? When should we use which?

```
@array = (1,2,3);
func(@array);
func(\@array);

sub func {
    ...
}
```

Also, how do I imitate pass-by-value in Perl? Is using `@_` the only way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> AFAIK, in both functions, arguments are passed by reference and in both functions we can change the elements of @array in the main program.

"change the elements of", yes. However, in the `func(@array)` case, the sub has no means to make other changes to the array (truncating it, pushing, popping, slicing, passing a reference to something else, even undef'ing it).

I would avoid using the term "passed by reference", since the mechanism is completely different than Perl's references. It is less overloaded :) to say that in the sub, `@_`'s elements start off aliased to the elements passed to the sub.

Answer (score 22):

It's impossible to pass arrays to subs. Subs take a list of scalars for argument. (And that's the only thing they can return too.)

You can pass a reference to an array:

```
func(\@array)
```

You can pass the elements of an array:

```
func(@array)
```

---

> When should we use which?

If you want to pass more than just the elements of the array (e.g. pass `$x`, `$y` and `@a`), it can become tricky unless you pass a reference.

If you're going to process lists (e.g. `sum mysub grep { ... } ...`), you might not want to pass a reference.

If you want to modify the array (as opposed to just modifying the existing elements of the array), you need to pass a reference.

It can be more efficient to pass a reference for long arrays, since creating and putting one reference on the stack is faster than creating an alias for each element of a large array. This will rarely be an issue, though.

It's usually decided by one of the first two of the above. Beyond that, it's mostly a question of personal preference.

---

> Also, how do I imitate pass-by-value in Perl?

```
sub foo {
   my ($x) = @_;   # Changing $x doesn't change the argument.
   ...
}

sub foo {
   my @a = @_;   # Changing @a or its contents
   ...           #    doesn't change the arguments.
}
```

Comment: `(And that's the only thing they can return too.)` no, they can return arrays. To see it check out the difference between `sub { return (qw/a b c/);}` and `sub { @array = (qw/a b c/); return @array }` in scalar context. This first returns `c`, the second returns `3`, the number of elements in the returned array!!!

Comment: @Joel, no they can't return arrays. `sub { return (qw/a b c/);}` in scalar context returns one scalar ("c"), and `sub { @array = (qw/a b c/); return @array }` in scalar returns one scalar (3). The scalar is returned by `qw` or `@array` before `return` is even evaluated.

Comment: @TLP, There must have been an error in your test. Try `perl -E"say scalar sub { return (qw/a b c/);}->()"`

Comment: @Joel, You can see what happens when you return an array using this XS code: `void f() { dXSARGS; EXTEND(SP, 1); ST(0) = newAV(); XSRETURN(1); }`. If you do `$x = f();`, you get `Bizarre copy of ARRAY in scalar assignment`.

Answer (score 4):

`func(\@array)` passes a reference. `func(@array)` passes a list (of the elements in `@array`). As Keith pointed out, these elements are passed by reference. However, you can make a copy inside the sub in order to pass by value.

What you are after is this:

```
sub func {
    my @array = @_;
}
```

This will pass a copy of the arguments of `func` to `@array`, which is a local variable within the scope of the subroutine.

Documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html)

Comment: Actually `func(@array)` passes the elements of `@array` by reference.  For example: `sub func { map { $_ ++ } @_; } } my @arr = ( 10, 20, 30); func(@arr);` will set `@arr` to `(11, 21, 31)` -- and `func(10, 20, 30)` will fail with "Modification of a read-only value attempted".  One purpose of the `my @arr = @_;` idiom is to copy the `@_` values to a local array, to achieve the effect of pass-by-value.

Comment: As `perldoc perlsub` says: "Any arguments passed in show up in the array `@_`.  Therefore, if you called a function with two arguments, those would be stored in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`.  The array `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters."

Comment: re "by reference", see my answer